# Error Code: 1062 Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am constantly getting a Error code 1062: Duplicate Entry.
The first row insert, but then it fails on the same ID.
So everytime I hit execute it will increment: 1466, 1467, 1468, 1469.
And each time there is the same record entered, so I am assuming the autoincrement is only working for the first iteration.

Table:

```
'entity':  

CREATE TABLE `entity` (  
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
  `reg_num` varchar(45) NOT NULL,  
  `enterprise_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1474 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT=\'Comment'
```

Stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `tp_to_entityPROC`()
    DETERMINISTIC
    COMMENT 'stored'
BEGIN
    DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE Tid INT;
    DECLARE Tt_name TEXT;

    DECLARE allt CURSOR FOR 
                SELECT training_provider_id, training_provider_name 
                FROM training_providers;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;

    OPEN allt;
    read_loop: LOOP
        IF done THEN
             LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        FETCH allt INTO Tid, Tt_name;

        SET @id = 0;
        SET @t_name = 0;
        SET @id = Tid;
        SET @t_name = Tt_name;
        SET @empty = '';

        if (@id != 0) THEN
            INSERT INTO entity (name)
            VALUES (@t_name);
            SET @my_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

            IF @my_id != 0 THEN
                UPDATE training_awarded_providers 
                SET training_awarded_provider_id = @my_id
                WHERE training_awarded_provider_id = @id;
            END IF;
        END IF;

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE allt; 

END
```

Comment: When testing your code, I receive the following warning: Field 'reg_num' doesn't have a default value. Are you sure the above information is accurate? That being said, I do see a potential error in your stored routine: your check of the variable 'done' should come before the insert, I think.

Comment: Tim I have updated with the exact code, I had removed a few things to make it shorter

Comment: I can not reproduce the error. The following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a6519/1) sample, you can see the code, some things do not seem to be working correctly.

Comment: I have another stored proc of the same nature and it works exactly, `reg_num` does not contain `null` it is just `blank ('')`. Furthermore, your claims can be ruled out as when I run the procedure the first record is inserted perfectly (it fails because the auto increment seems to have failed to increment) and it tries to insert with the same id. So, auto-increment not working.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the exact error of `duplicate entry` but your posted code is not going to work.

Your Table schema

```
CREATE TABLE `entity` (  
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,  
  `reg_num` varchar(45) NOT NULL <-- Here it's non null column
```

In your store procedure you are trying to insert `null` to `reg_num` column which will never succeed

```
if (@id != 0) THEN
INSERT INTO entity (name)
VALUES (@t_name);
```

Comment: It seems inconceivable, and I'm trying to portray the problem I am having. But I have another table called 'service_providers' with the exact same table makeup and an almost identical stored proc and the stored procedure worked perfect (NULL was not inserted into `reg_num` ) it is just left blank ('')